# How to remove namespace shortcuts parsing SOAP as XML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap, onvif

For example i have a string like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <d:ProbeMatches>
        <d:ProbeMatch>
            <d:Types>dn:NetworkVideoTransmitter</d:Types>
            <d:Scopes>onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/Streaming onvif://www.onvif.org/type/video_encoder onvif://www.onvif.org/type/audio_encoder onvif://www.onvif.org/hardware/IPCAM onvif://www.onvif.org/name/IPNC onvif://www.onvif.org/location/</d:Scopes>
            <d:XAddrs>http://192.168.0.36:8080/onvif/device_service</d:XAddrs>
            <d:MetadataVersion>1</d:MetadataVersion>
        </d:ProbeMatch>
    </d:ProbeMatches>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

And i need to convert it to `array` so i use `simplexml_load_string`, but the main problem is that the result can be different... In one case it cat be `<d:Types>`, in other `<Types xmlns=".*">` or some other shortcuts, which fully occurs in keys and i need to get adress as `['ProbeMatches']['ProbeMatch']['XAddrs']`